# How do I manipulate a content inside an <a> tag

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive-design

I'm facing some problems to align my icon with description to make it responsible. Actually, I have a card that contains a Title, Description and a div that has background-image inside, but If the screen is maximized, I need to set the description below the image, but if the screen is minimum-size the description should be displayed at the same line of image.

```css
.myCard {
  .card-link {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 9px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="myCard">
  <div class="container-fluid relative-position">
    <a class="col col-12 link-style" (click)="onClicked()">
      <div class="row content">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="information">
            <h1 id="title" role="heading" class="title">{{ title }}</h1>
            <p id="description" role="text" class="description">{{ description }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getURLfromImage()}">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example:**
[image: example image for card]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please remove the templating to make a [mcve]. You can find images at placeholder.com and remember to tag relevant tags. Angular seems quite relevant

Answer (score 2):

You can try with css grid and grid-areas :

```css
.card-link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items:  center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

#description { 
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3; 
} 

#description, #title {
  justify-self: left;
}


@media (max-width: 601px) {
  #description { 
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; 
  } 
  .image {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="myCard">
  <div class="container-fluid relative-position">
    <a class="col col-12 link-style" (click)="onClicked()">
      <div class="row content card-link">
        <h1 id="title" role="heading" class="title">title</h1>
        <p id="description" role="text" class="description">
          description description description description description description
          description description description description description description
         </p>
        <img class="col image" src="https://picsum.photos/70">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```